# How to parse array JSON to PHP Object?

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing, object

i have an error when i want to parse my json array to php object using looping foreach.

this is my error :

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testJSON\crul_json.php on line 49

and then this is my code

```
<?php

function http_request($url){
    // persiapkan curl
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // set user agent    
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

    // return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // tutup curl 
    curl_close($ch);      

    // mengembalikan hasil curl
    return $output;
}

$profile = http_request("http://localhost/testWebService/");

//json_output(400, $profile);

$json_format = json_encode($profile);
//echo $json_format;

// ubah string JSON menjadi array
$hasil = json_decode($json_format, TRUE);
$hdcode = var_dump($hasil);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Curl Data JSON</title>
</head>

<body>

<br>
<p> 
    <?php
    foreach ($hasil  as $i):   
    ?>
Nama: <?php echo $hasil->id_mhs; ?><br>

<?php endforeach;?>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help me to resolve this error for the invalid looping? 
thank you:)

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($hasil)`? and why you save it in a variable `$hdcode` ?

Comment: That's because $profile is a string, so encoding it as a string will decode as a string, also I noticed that you put a `TRUE` in your decode.  That decodes it as an array and not as an object

Answer (score 0):

Is the response from the webservice JSON? If so you don't need to json_encode it.

Also since you are passing true as the second param to json_decode it will be an array instead of an object. You can call

```
$hasil = json_decode($json_format);
```

To get an object.

Also in your foreach you need to use `$i` instead of `$hasil`.